# Port Forwarding issue on FritzBox

Tags: port-forwarding, ipv6, fritzbox

I am running a server on a Raspberry Pi which is connected to a FritzBox. From within the network, I can reach the server both via the local IP and via the registered URL. From the outside, it is however not working.

This is how I set up the Port Forwarding:
[image: FritzBox Screenshot]

the 'HTTP and HTTPS server' items have TCP protocol, the other ones are with UDP. However, when checking my ports [here](https://www.subnetonline.com/pages/ipv6-network-tools/online-ipv6-port-scanner.php), the port seems to be closed: 
[image: portcheck]

The apache server on the raspberry pi is configured to allow at least everything on Port 80, as the file `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` has a block `<VirtualHost *:80> ... <VirtualHost>`.

Rather than getting the ultimate solution, I'd like to gather ideas on what ELSE could potentially block requests from the outside? Is there a way to identify whether the request reaches the router, but not the raspberry, to narrow down the problem?

Comment: I do connect to the device address. Infact, I copy the ip6 from `ifconfig` on the RPi into the browser.

Comment: What is shown in the Fritz Box are the local IP adresses, aren't they?

Comment: Disregarding ULA, there is no such thing as a local address with IPv6.

Comment: Pardon my wording. As far as I understand the `:: ... :4b2c` address from the screenshot is some constant assignment for the rpi, similar to the fix IP4 address. As this does not appear in `ifconfig`, I disregard it for this purpose.

Comment: @DanielB: That makes as much sense as "Disregarding RFC1918, there is no such thing as a local address with IPv4"...

Comment: @grawity I disagree. ULA is not generally used when access the Internet using IPv6. As such, it is IMHO acceptable not to consider it with topics like this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When setting up port forwarding for IPv4, the process is straightforward: You only have one public IP address, after all.

With IPv6, the FritzBox firewall works differently: There is no NAT involved, so traffic arrives bound for the device’s own IPv6 address. The firewall has to be set up to allow traffic to this specific address. That’s what the “IPv6 Interface-ID” in the FritzBox user interface is: The local part of your device’s IPv6 address.

Consider this example:

[image: FritzBox Port Forwarding]

At the bottom you can see the actual IPv6 address and port that are allowed through the firewall.

For you, this IPv6 address and the actual device IPv6 address do not match. As such, traffic is blocked by the firewall.

If for whatever reason the *permanent* suffix (usually based on the MAC address) is not correctly picked up by the UI, you need to manually put in the correct one.

You may have to change the device’s IPv6 settings like disabling Privacy Extensions for it to actually have a predictable IPv6 address.

Comment: 2 days of struggling and trying all sorts until I found this post! Thanks so much. For anyone else who, like me, took a while to figure out what "permanent suffix" means here, you can copy the last four values from the IPv6 address the site 'test-ipv6.com' shows you.

Comment: @JackAidley It is important to note that with IPv6 Privacy Extensions active, the address you see with services like that is an ephemeral one. It will be invalid in a matter of hours. You need the standard SLAAC address (or, if you have DHCPv6, that one), because its local part will always be the same, even when the prefix changes.

Comment: So the value marked 'IPv6 address' on ipconfig rather than the one marked 'Temporary IPv6 address'?

Comment: @JackAidley That’s correct.

Answer (score 0):

The Fritzbox in my case changes the ipv6 Interface-ID to suit itself. That means it does not match the one you enter which corresponds with your host.