# How to configure VirtualBox NAT network with IPv6?

Tags: virtualbox, ipv6, nat

I am running an externally-acessible server inside a VM. My local router is configured to use DDS to map my IP address to a domain I own and to forward packets to ports 80 and 443 to my Windows PC. The VirtualBox VM is configured with NAT network and following port forwarding rules:

[image]

Until recently everything worked like a charm with IPv4. Unfortunately, I recently changed my DSL provider and they use DS Lite tunnel, which means that I don't have a public IPv4 address, only IPv6. Thus, I have reconfigured my DDNS rules to map my domain to my dynamic IP address. It appears packets arrive to my PC*, but not forwarded to the VM.

Why? Do I need to configure IPv6 somewhere and/or use a different network type in "Attached to:" dropdown? Can I somehow forward IPv6 packets to IPv4 address inside VM?

* actually, when running a server on the host, I can't access it via my external IPv6 address either. I get redirected to my router page instead. So maybe I also need to fix my router configuration somehow. I think it's related to "IPv6 Prefix" and this is a new concept for me. There is also apparently a dedicated IPv6 address for my PC in port forwarding settings, which seems to imply there are multiple external IPv6 addresses assigned to me. Looks like I need to read more about it.

Comment: TCP on IPv6 is not the same as TCP on IPv4, they’re two distinct protocols. That’s why this isn’t working. // As for the second case, your “external IPv6 address” should be the same as the “internal IPv6 address”. Your PC should have a globally routable IPv6 address. That’s what goes into the DDNS domain name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it might be in theory possible for VirtualBox's NAT implementation to forward IPv6 connections to an IPv4 host, such protocol translation tends to introduce a lot of complications, such as "what IPv4 source address should the target host see?" (as the original v6 address of course cannot fit in the IPv4 header). So the only options in practice are v4-to-v4 and v6-to-v6.

The default NAT network in VirtualBox does not support IPv6. You will need to open **"Tools → Network"** in the main VirtualBox window and create a custom NAT network there, enabling IPv6 and configuring some address prefix; then you'll see that the "Port Forwarding" tab now has both 'IPv4' and 'IPv6' sub-tabs.

Then, in the VM's settings, switch the network interface from "NAT" to "NAT Network" and select the network you just created.

(Unlike the default NAT mode, these custom NAT networks can be shared between multiple VMs, therefore port forwarding is configured via network settings and not via VM settings.)

---

**Option B:** Instead of NAT mode, use the **"Bridged" mode** that allows the VM to be directly present in your main LAN. The VM will then have its own IPv6 address (and its own IPv4 LAN address), the same way as your Windows host does, so you won't need port-forwarding configuration at all.

**Option C:** There are HTTP reverse proxies and TCP proxies that could be run on the Windows host, proxying the connections to a VM (either through VBox NAT "port forwarding" or through a "host-only" interface). Proxies *can* translate between IPv4 and IPv6 as they do not attempt to preserve the original IP address; they just make a new connection from the host's own IP. (The original client IP would be provided through X-Forwarded-For or similar methods.)

**Option D:** Windows has a built-in TCP proxy service which similarly supports relaying between IPv4 and IPv6. You can find it in `netsh` under `interface portproxy` (try the `add` command). It doesn't support X-Forwarded-For or anything such.

---

**Prefixes** (expanded from comments)

- "Prefixes" are the same thing in both IPv4 and IPv6; they just indicate a network (an address range) of some specific size. For example, your home LAN's internal prefix is most likely 192.168.1.0/24, with the "/24" being the prefix length in bits (a more compact way of writing the 255.255.255.0 netmask).

  The term is uncommon in the context of residential IPv4 connections, as those get – at best – just a single address that's not worth calling a "prefix", when the only thing it's a prefix for is itself (though you could still call it a /32 prefix).

  With IPv6, meanwhile, the address pool is large enough that your ISP can *easily* afford assigning you multiple external addresses. But instead of leasing them individually to each device, the ISP assigns you a whole subnet at once and lets your own router take care of the rest – the "IPv6 prefix" is simply the IPv6 address range that's used for your network.

  (As in IPv4, the prefix length such as /64 is still just a way of writing down the netmask, but it's *much* more compact than "ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:0:0:0:0".)
- Your router leases your LAN prefix using DHCPv6-PD ("Prefix Delegation") in much the same way as it would lease an IPv4 address using traditional DHCP. This allows the router to directly distribute public IPv6 addresses to LAN devices, which means there is no need for it to perform NAT anymore – neither outbound nor inbound, thus "port forwarding" rules aren't applied to IPv6 connections either; clients just directly reach to your LAN addresses. (The router still has a *firewall* to protect the LAN, though.)

  (Individual IPv6 subnets *almost* always use a /64 prefix; that's what your home router gets by default for your LAN, but your ISP is usually capable of assigning you a larger network (shorter prefix) such as /60 or /56 that's then subdivided into a decent amount of /64 subnets. When you're using the "[Unique Local Prefix Generator](https://unique-local-ipv6.com/)", you're also meant to subdivide the /48 into /64-sized subnets.)
- Once the prefix is obtained, the router announces it to the LAN using ICMPv6 Router Advertisement; each device then **independently** decides what suffix(es) to append to it and generates its own address(es) that way. The router does not keep track of 'leased' IPv6 addresses.

  Depending on OS, the address suffix can be either completely static (e.g. MAC-based) or partially static (only changing when the prefix changes). Also, PCs will often have "IPv6 Privacy Extensions" enabled and will generate *additional* temporary IPv6 addresses alongside the permanent one; there's a separate thread about disabling that.

  (The protocol described above is "SLAAC". Although IPv6 does have DHCPv6 as a more traditional option for address assignment, it is quite uncommon.)
- Since each device now has an unique external address, DynDNS clients should be run on that specific device – and yes that means you'll need a separate subdomain for each server you have. However, your ISP **should** allow you to have a static IPv6 prefix avoiding the need for DynDNS, as they can very well afford it… unless they decided to charge a "Because we can" tax. (Or unless you're in Germany, where you apparently need to explicitly opt in to having a static prefix due to laws?)

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. While poking around, I have learned about "IPv6 Prefix" and this is something new to me. I have also realized that running a server on my host PC does not work either and for some reason, I get redirected to my router page when accessing external domain page. IIUC this is also related to "IPv6 Prefix". Apparently, in IPv6, one can have multiple IP addresses and each host on LAN has its own address. I will read more about this and, if I manage to get this work, I will accept it as a valid solution.

Comment: Yes, that's kind of the whole point behind IPv6. In practice for you the main difference is that instead of your router's IP address, your clients (and your DNS records) need to directly use your Windows host's IP address – the router will still have _firewall_ rules to protect the LAN, but it will not do any address translation. (In theory, you could make it even more direct and give the VM its own IPv6 address as well.)

Comment: Interesting, so I guess I can choose Bridged and then have external IPv6 for my VM. How do these get assigned? Does the router allocate them? Where do I configure DynDNS in this case? On the VM or the router?

Comment: Really you could probably have used Bridged mode even with IPv4, in the same way... Each host independently generates its own IPv6 address(es) – the router announces the address prefix (using an ICMPv6 Router Advertisement) and the host decides on what suffix to use (e.g. MAC-address-based suffixes used to be common, recognized by `ff:fe` in the middle); DHCPv6-based address assignment exists but is rarely used – and since each host has its unique address, the DynDNS updates should be made from that specific host.

Comment: As for the prefix to use on the LAN – your router uses DHCPv6-PD to lease your public prefix from the ISP, much like it used to obtain your IPv4 address, whereas for VirtualBox NAT a [private](https://unique-local-ipv6.com/) prefix might be enough.

Comment: Had to solve some other issues (http://superuser.com/a/1404132/12223, http://stackoverflow.com/a/32621449/178315 and https://wimsworld.wordpress.com/2022/07/18/google-domains-dynamic-dns-and-ipv6/ helped), but ultimately made it work. Thanks a ton for all your help.